# How to update User roles of IBM MQ running on cloud

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to IBM MQ running on cloud  using REST API. I started with the documents [link1](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-develop-mq-rest-api/) and also refereed [link2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q128725_.htm) but  looks like these document talk about on-prem instance of IBM MQ.  I generated LTPA token and when i execute send message API, i get below error with 403 http error code. I understand that here the user i am using has no proper rights.  I am not getting any documentation which explain how i can configure the user roles for IBM MQ running on cloud. Anyone has tried it and can shed some light ?

```
    "explanation": "The authenticated principal is not authorized to perform the requested REST API operation.",
    "message": "MQWB0103E: Not authorized to put to 'queue1'.",
```

Comment: Step 2 in your link1 document has a link to "Getting started with the messaging REST API" - did you follow the instructions in there? If only some, can you detail in your question what you did to set up the mqweb server and then we can help to find what steps you missed out.

Comment: Maybe you find better answers in the IBM Cloud documentation? For MQ on IBM Cloud you can start here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/mqcloud?topic=mqcloud-mqoc_administer_mq_username and look at the pages adjacent to this page.

Answer (score 0):

As @habercode states your starting point should be the "Invoking the queue manager REST APIs" documentation For IBM MQ on Cloud - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/mqcloud?topic=mqcloud-mqoc_qm_rest_api

As the doc states you will need a MQ username and API key to authenticate.

> Get your MQ username and API key from your service instance in IBM
> Cloud, then ...

base64 encode the combination, before using it with basic authentication.

Once you can authenticate, you can use the REST API documentation to configure your API calls.